# A big plot having all subplots as mentioned in the description

Tags: python, pandas

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmt3D.png)

Please help to generated this kind of graphs in a single shot. This is required for analysis. Bar graphs are needed. A structure to this kind of output will really help.

```
Alphabet    year    month   month_name  Quantity
A   2019    4   April   1
A   2019    5   May 15
A   2019    6   June    23
A   2019    7   July    23.17647059
B   2019    4   April   2
B   2019    5   May 16
B   2019    6   June    24
B   2019    7   July    23.60784314
C   2019    4   April   3
C   2019    5   May 17
C   2019    6   June    25
C   2019    7   July    24.03921569
D   2019    4   April   4
D   2019    5   May 18
D   2019    6   June    26
D   2019    7   July    24.47058824
E   2019    4   April   5
E   2019    5   May 19
E   2019    6   June    27
F   2019    4   April   6
F   2019    5   May 20
F   2019    6   June    28
G   2019    4   April   7
G   2019    5   May 21
G   2019    6   June    0
H   2019    4   April   8
H   2019    5   May 22
I   2019    4   April   9
J   2019    4   April   10
K   2019    4   April   11
L   2019    4   April   12
M   2019    4   April   13
N   2019    4   April   14
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("1.csv")

rows = df.Alphabet.unique()
cols = df.month_name.unique()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows.shape[0],cols.shape[0], 
                       sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize =(16,16))
ax = ax.reshape(-1)

count = 0
for letter in rows:
    for month in cols:
        mask = (df.Alphabet == letter) & (df.month_name == month)
        df[mask].plot(x='year', y='Quantity', kind='bar', ax=ax[count])
        ax[count].set_ylabel(letter)
        ax[count].set_title(month)
        count+=1

plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, top=2, right=None)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-11797c631676> in <module>
     17     for month in cols:
     18         mask = (df.Alphabet == letter) & (df.month_name == month)
---> 19         df[mask].plot(x='year', y='Quantity', kind='bar', ax=ax[count])
     20         ax[count].set_ylabel(letter)
     21         ax[count].set_title(month)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    845                     data.columns = label_name
    846 
--> 847         return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    848 
    849     __call__.__doc__ = __doc__

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     59             kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     60     plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 61     plot_obj.generate()
     62     plot_obj.draw()
     63     return plot_obj.result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in generate(self)
    263         self._make_plot()
    264         self._add_table()
--> 265         self._make_legend()
    266         self._adorn_subplots()
    267 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py in _make_legend(self)
    570 
    571             if len(handles) > 0:
--> 572                 ax.legend(handles, labels, loc="best", title=title)
    573 
    574         elif self.subplots and self.legend:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in legend(self, *args, **kwargs)
    404         if len(extra_args):
    405             raise TypeError('legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments')
--> 406         self.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(self, handles, labels, **kwargs)
    407         self.legend_._remove_method = self._remove_legend
    408         return self.legend_

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py in __init__(self, parent, handles, labels, loc, numpoints, markerscale, markerfirst, scatterpoints, scatteryoffsets, prop, fontsize, borderpad, labelspacing, handlelength, handleheight, handletextpad, borderaxespad, columnspacing, ncol, mode, fancybox, shadow, title, title_fontsize, framealpha, edgecolor, facecolor, bbox_to_anchor, bbox_transform, frameon, handler_map)
    573 
    574         # init with null renderer
--> 575         self._init_legend_box(handles, labels, markerfirst)
    576 
    577         # If shadow is activated use framealpha if not

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py in _init_legend_box(self, handles, labels, markerfirst)
    831                 # original artist/handle.
    832                 handle_list.append(handler.legend_artist(self, orig_handle,
--> 833                                                          fontsize, handlebox))
    834                 handles_and_labels.append((handlebox, textbox))
    835 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py in legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox)
    113         artists = self.create_artists(legend, orig_handle,
    114                                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height,
--> 115                                       fontsize, handlebox.get_transform())
    116 
    117         # create_artists will return a list of artists.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py in create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans)
    297         p = self._create_patch(legend, orig_handle,
    298                                xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize)
--> 299         self.update_prop(p, orig_handle, legend)
    300         p.set_transform(trans)
    301         return [p]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py in update_prop(self, legend_handle, orig_handle, legend)
     70     def update_prop(self, legend_handle, orig_handle, legend):
     71 
---> 72         self._update_prop(legend_handle, orig_handle)
     73 
     74         legend._set_artist_props(legend_handle)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py in _update_prop(self, legend_handle, orig_handle)
     63             self._default_update_prop(legend_handle, orig_handle)
     64         else:
---> 65             self._update_prop_func(legend_handle, orig_handle)
     66 
     67     def _default_update_prop(self, legend_handle, orig_handle):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend_handler.py in update_from_first_child(tgt, src)
     36 
     37 def update_from_first_child(tgt, src):
---> 38     tgt.update_from(src.get_children()[0])
     39 
     40 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The output should be as mentioned in the image link attached. It should be based on Quantity

[Output for Graph--[Clickhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h6Bn.png)]

Comment: show the sample code that you have tried so far.

Comment: There are a lot of graphs, different combinations of x-axes and y-axes, different types of graphs (barplot, lineplots, histograms), please provide more information about what you want.

Comment: Hi, They should be bar plots...

Comment: I assume the X-axes is year and y-axes is quantity, right?

Comment: X axes - "Month-year". Ex: Apr-2019. Y- qty.,

Comment: @jcaliz, I'm getting an error. Please help. I am not able to update code here. Can I ping you here or on gmail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for, please note that you might have to modify the `subplots_adjust` parameters to get the right margins, and the `figsize` to display the image in the right size:

```
rows = df.Alphabet.unique()
cols = df.month_name.unique()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(rows.shape[0],cols.shape[0], 
                       sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize =(16,16))
ax = ax.reshape(-1)

count = 0
for letter in rows:
    for month in cols:
        mask = (df.Alphabet == letter) & (df.month_name == month)
        ax[count].set_ylabel(letter)
        ax[count].set_title(month)
        if (mask.sum() != 0):
            df[mask].plot(x='year', y='Quantity', kind='bar', ax=ax[count])
        count+=1


plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, top=2, right=None)
```

Comment: This is awesome but I'm getting an error. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. I have updated the code in description. Can I ping you on gmail. If yes, please provide email id

Comment: @BdsTeja please edit your question with the error or maybe post more sample data, this is a general code based on the sample you provided.